# Initializing a dictionnary with a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, syntax, initialization

I would like to initialize my dictionary res with empty vectors 'W1':[], 'W2':[] up to 100, but I don't know how to iterate on the i value.

`res = {'lambda' : []} for i in range(0,99): res.update('W'{i+1}: [])`

then later in my code, I have the same problem when I want to add to each of these 100 vectors a value.

`for i in range(0,99): res['W'{i+1}].append(W[i])`

Thank you!

Comment: You're overcomplicating it: `res = {f'W{i}':[] for i in range(100)}`. But I wonder if a list wouldn't be a better datastructure for this.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a dictionary with 100 items (W0 - W99), all being a key to an empty list.

```
{"W" + str(i): [] for i in range(100)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```py
res = {}
keys = 100
for i in range(1, keys+1):
    res.update({f'W{i}': []})

print(res)
```

##### Output

```
{'W1': [], 'W2': [], 'W3': [], ...
```